# Is there any way to create popup window while clicking build button in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a requirement where I need to get user's confirmation on clicking `'Build'` button in Jenkins "Build with Parameters". It should be a dialog box or popup window on clicking the build button.

When I search for it, almost all of the answers related to `input` condition or adding a choice parameter. But I would like to have a proper dialog box which should display the parameter values and 'Do you want to proceed' 'Yes/No' button, if 'yes' build should proceed, if 'no' return to Build with parameters page.

Is this can be achieved through JavaScript or Groovy script? Any one having idea about this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem atm.